# Why is a varwidth incorrectly vertically centered by \raisebox{-0.5\height}?

Tags: boxes, dimensions, height, varwidth, raise

I was creating a pseudocode/JavaScript comparison table, and wanted to typeset algorithms written with the algorithm2e package vertically centered in table cells.  Out-of-the box, algorithm2e can't do this, but I modded the code, and everything but one point seems to be working.  That's this: algorithm2e normally places pseudocode lines in boxes out to \hsize, but in the table context I want their natural size, so I used the varwidth environment.  And that has broken the vertical centering.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\verticalcenter}[1]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
  \verticalcenter{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\hsize}%
      text\par
      text\par
      text\par
    \end{varwidth}%
  }&\verticalcenter{\rule{1cm}{1pt}}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: A table with the centered rule appearing well above the center of the pseudocode]

where the centerline is well above the center of the text.

I tried to dive in the varwidth code, but nothing is jumping out at me.  How can I fix the varwidth's dimensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A box also has a depth, taking it into account yields:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\verticalcenter}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.5\dimexpr\height-\depth\relax}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
  \verticalcenter{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\hsize}%
      text\par
      text\par
      text\par
    \end{varwidth}%
  }&\verticalcenter{\rule{1cm}{1pt}}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Aha.  I had tried accounting for depth with another \raisebox (not knowing about \dimexpr), but of course I tried it in the original document, not in the MWE, where things still looked off.  Thanks for the fix; I now have some unintended whitespace to hunt down.